# How to create InterpolatingFunction from data?

Tags: complex, interpolation

If I have a function at a number of non-uniformly spaced data points:

```
youtReal[7.8]=2.0332;, youtReal[8.54]=6.24352354;..................
```

......... and the   imaginary parts:

```
youtImag[7.8]=2.54345345; youtImag[8.54]=-5.2434;.................
```

Is there an easy way to generate an `InterpolatingFunction` from this data consisting of complex values i.e. so I have

```
yout[7.8]=2.0332+2.54345345I;
```

and can also just get an interpolated value for say `yout[8.12]` and so on.

To make this more concrete, the initial data is read in from a text file that looks like

```
youtReal[39.983881559265192985] =0.003175121157662356963;
 youtImag[39.983881559265192985] =-0.025570345562818877981;
 youtReal[39.945803445544929806] =0.0030816430773355882379;
 youtImag[39.945803445544929806] =-0.025607948113924885628;
 youtReal[39.907725331824666628] =0.0029879382430246325535;
 youtImag[39.907725331824666628] =-0.025645261479980185081;
 youtReal[39.869647218104403449] =0.0028940073645911109315;
 youtImag[39.869647218104403449] =-0.025682284691974913792;
  youtReal[39.831569104384140271] =0.0027998511548903118804;
  youtImag[39.831569104384140271] =-0.025719016782491712295;
  youtReal[39.793490990663877092] =0.0027054703297639490629;
 youtImag[39.793490990663877092] =-0.025755456785713930289;
 youtReal[39.755412876943613914] =0.0026108656080328711776;
 youtImag[39.755412876943613914] =-0.025791603737433792661;
youtReal[39.717334763223350736] =0.00251603771148972405;
 youtImag[39.717334763223350736] =-0.025827456675060525123;
 .
 .
 .
```

and so on all the way down to around `youtReal[~29]`. So I read this in then have a function with quite arbitrarily defined value points, and lots and lots of them. I don't have a nice list of points I can just feed into `ListInterpolation` ab initio, I need to somehow generate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DownValues` to get a list of function definitions:

```
real = ReleaseHold[List @@@ DownValues[youtReal] /. youtReal[t_] -> t];
imag = ReleaseHold[List @@@ DownValues[youtImag] /. youtImag[t_] -> t];
```

Then assuming you get the real and imaginary parts for a particular point defined in order, you can now generate your list of points:

```
Thread[{real, imag}] /. {{t_, a_}, {t_, b_}} -> {t, a + b I}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

InterpolatingFunction works fine with complex data. For instance, modifying the first example in the help file to make it complex-valued and unevenly spaced

```
 points = {{0, 0 + I}, {2, 3 + 2 I}, {3, 4}, {4, 3 - 2 I}, {5, 0}};
 ifun = Interpolation[points]
```

allows you to find interpolated values at points such as

```
 ifun[2.3]
```

Comment: Sorry, I am aware of this already. My problem is I have a very large set of data, split in real and complex parts as in the OP, it's not in advance in a nice list like this.  It's written as a function (originally read in from a large text file) which takes the form showed in my OP. The fact that the values are complex is just another headache on top. The main problem is the data points are non uniformly spread and there could be say 1000 of them.

Comment: updated the OP to try to make this clearer